# Bootstrap dropdown - trigger by external button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 dropdowns. I need the button that triggers the dropdown to open to live outside of the parent element (under A). How can I do it via Jquery or JS?

```
<div class="A"> 
    <!-- need button to live here -->
</div>

<div class="B">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown button </button>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap check parents and HTML elements before starting the toggle, you can actually move the button outside and it will works fine, the problem is about the <div> wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do that using `attribute` but you can use jquery to controlle the drop down, for example:

html:

```
<div class="A"> 
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dropdown-target="#dropdown1" type="button" aria-expanded="false"></button>
</div>
<div class="B">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown button </button>
    <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown1">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

js :

```
$('[data-dropdown-target]').on('click', function() {
    $($(this).attr('data-dropdown-target')).dropdown('toggle');
});
```

if you want to use the button like the default button, including the closing events on clicking outside..., you can use this :

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    $target = $(e.target);
    $('.dropdown.show').each((i, el) => {
        if(
            !$($target).closest('[data-dropdown-target="#'+$(el).attr('id')+'"]').length &&
            $('[data-dropdown-target="#'+$(el).attr('id')+'"]').length !== 0 &&
            $target !== $(el) &&
            !$($target).closest(el).length
        ) {
            $(el).dropdown('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Cool! Your "js" solution works. But I can't get the "default button" solution to work, the '$('.dropdown.show').each((i, el) => {' is not firing up at all!

Comment: fyi, for those trying it, change 'dorpdown' to 'dropdown'

Comment: Should it be "$(document).on('click'" ? Would that try to fire with every click on the body?

Comment: the code in "$(document).on('click'" is used to close the dropdown when you click outside the button or the dropdown it self, btw this code work not for only one button you can use it for multiple buttons just use `data-dropdown-target` and dropdown's `id` right. sorry for the mistake (`data-dorpdown-target`) i fixed it now.